# Is it possible to change multiple values, by different amounts concurrently?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to resize and relocate an object, by changing the x, y and area values, all at the same time.
I can do them one after another by running 3 separate for loops, but the animation needs to be smooth and as one.

I tried nesting another for loop inside the function but that provides the same result as 1 loop has to finish before the next one starts.
The only way I can find to complete it is to make 3 separate scripts and run all 3 at the same time.

```
SSxPOSA =  0.00
SSxPOSB =  -12.00
SSyPOSA =  0.00
SSyPOSB =  -6.55
SSsizeA =  1.00
SSsizeB =  0.2

function SSBox1X()
    for i = SSxPOSA, SSxPOSB, 0.1
    do
    Object1X( i );
    end;
end;
function SSBox1Y()
    for i = SSyPOSA, SSyPOSB, 0.5
    do
    Object1Y( i );
    end;
end;
function SSBox1Scale()
    for i = SSsizeA, SSsizeB, 0.8
    do
    Object1Scale( i );
    end;
end;

SSBox1X();
SSBox1Y();
SSBox1Scale();
```

Happy to read and learn best practice

Comment: What do any of these functions do? When do their results become visible?

Comment: Write a generator function that changes all three values and use it in a `for ... in` loop.

Comment: BTW, the end values are lower than the start values so your steps should be negative.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, something like this should work:

```
function xys()
  local x, y, s = SSxPOSA, SSyPOSA, SSsizeA
  return coroutine.wrap(
         function()
           while x >= SSxPOSB and y >= SSyPOSB and s >= SSsizeB do
             coroutine.yield(x,y,s)
             x = x - 0.1
             y = y - 0.5
             s = s - 0.8
           end
         end)
end

SSxPOSA =  0.00
SSxPOSB =  -12.00

SSyPOSA =  0.00
SSyPOSB =  -6.55

SSsizeA =  1.00
SSsizeB =  0.2

for x,y,s in xys() do
  print(x,y,s)
  --Object1X(x)
  --Object1Y(y)
  --Object1Scale(s)
end
```

And, because of floating point comparison not always yielding the expected result, it's probably better to convert to integers and divide just before using.  Like so:

```
function xys()
  local x, y, s = SSxPOSA, SSyPOSA, SSsizeA
  return coroutine.wrap(
         function()
           while x >= SSxPOSB and y >= SSyPOSB and s >= SSsizeB do
             coroutine.yield(x/100,y/100,s/100)
             x = x - 10
             y = y - 50
             s = s - 80
           end
         end)
end

SSxPOSA =  0
SSxPOSB =  -1200

SSyPOSA =  0
SSyPOSB =  -655

SSsizeA =  100
SSsizeB =  20

for x,y,s in xys() do
  print(x,y,s)
  --Object1X(x)
  --Object1Y(y)
  --Object1Scale(s)
end
```

You can also do it without coroutines:

```
function xys()
  local x, y, s = SSxPOSA, SSyPOSA, SSsizeA
  return function()
           if x < SSxPOSB or y < SSyPOSB or s < SSsizeB then return end
           local xx, yy, ss = x/100, y/100, s/100
           x = x - 10
           y = y - 50
           s = s - 80
           return xx,yy,ss
         end
end
```